# USB Microphone Not Working

Tags: pi-4, raspbian-buster, microphone

I am trying to create a magic mirror with my Raspberry Pi 4 (buster) that has voice recognition so I am using a [usb sound card](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00OJ5AV8I) with a [3.5 mm microphone](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B016C4ZG74). The problem is that I have configured my alsa settings so that I can hear test audio crystal clear through the headphones part of the sound card, but the microphone records null.

`lsusb`:

```
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 248a:8367 Maxxter 
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0d8c:0014 C-Media Electronics, Inc. Audio Adapter (Unitek Y-247A)
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 046d:c52f Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 2109:3431 VIA Labs, Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

`aplay -l && arecord -l`:

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 1: Device [USB Audio Device], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
**** List of CAPTURE Hardware Devices ****
card 1: Device [USB Audio Device], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

my `~/.asoundrc` file looks like:

```
pcm.!default {
        type asym
        playback.pcm "hw:1,0"
        capture.pcm "hw:1,0"
}

ctl.!default {
        type hw
        card 1
}
```

When I run the command `aplay /usr/share/sounds/alsa/Front_Center.wav` I can hear perfectly through my headphones. When I run `arecord --device=hw:1,0 --format S16_LE --rate 44100 -c1 -V mono test.wav` to record there is no sound coming in at all. when I play `test.wav` back there is no sound, not even static. I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Did you test the "usb sound card" on another computer? Maybe it has a problem on itself.

Comment: Check these links: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=120248#p814720 || https://stackoverflow.com/a/35063183/6602159 || https://iotbytes.wordpress.com/connect-configure-and-test-usb-microphone-and-speaker-with-raspberry-pi/ || https://scribles.net/voice-recording-on-raspberry-pi/

Comment: Thank you, but none of those links were helpful. I have no indication as to what could be wrong.

Comment: Are you sure the problem isn't with the USB Microphone card?

Comment: Well, I've tried two different USB cards at this point and both of them output sound just fine. With one of them, I could record static and very high volume sounds (clapping next to the mic) but only with the microphone that's attached to my earbuds. I could not figure out how to bypass the dB limit for input on Alsa so tthat didn't work for me.